# Magento 2 Migration: Volume Check Failed, Caused by Theme

Tags: magento2, error

I'm migrating my data from **Magento 1.9.2.0** to **Magento 2.0.0** on a **VPS running CentOS 6.7.** Everything is going just fine so far and any errors I've received I have been able to resolve. I'm stuck on this one, though.

I'm using a theme by Smartwave called Porto on my Magento 1 site. I don't plan to use this theme on the new site (they have an M2 version). This theme appears to be causing the error, but I don't know what to do.

I'm not sure what this message means or how to fix it:

> Incorrect value: porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode in:
>   eav_attribute.source_model for
>   attribute_code=sw_product_staticblock_tab_1`

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So today I tried again after getting some rest, and although I don't believe I found an answer, I did find a workaround:

Because I didn't need any of those attributes that gave me the errors, I went into the database via phpMyAdmin and simply deleted those entries. I continued with the migration and it worked!

I compared the entries with the others that were working correctly, and I didn't see anything that looked different in the formatting. So I'm still lost as to why I got the error, but my goal was to simply finish the migration and I was able to do that.

If anyone has any idea as to what may have happened, I'd love to know. For now, I'm all set. Thanks!